# Should i use the syphon or tap?

Tags: cider, first-time-brewer

I have recently started homebrewing, and my very first batch is a batch of cider that my wife requested I add raspberry and lime flavours to.

My question is, my brewing tub has a tap fitted about 1.5" above the bottom of the tub, but the tub also came with a syphon tube. Once all the sediment is settled, should i be safe to use the tap to bottle the cider, or should i always use the syphon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the siphon, since usually they're designed to take (almost) all the liquid while sucking up minimal sediment.  You probably have a little cap at the end of your siphon for that purpose.

If your sediment reaches below 1.5" I guess it doesn't matter if you prefer the tap. However, you might leave more liquid behind that way, if you don't actually have a lot of sediment.  Also, if you choose the tap, you should probably still run the liquid through a tube to your bottling bucket* or keg to keep exposure to oxygen down.

(*) you can skip the bottling bucket if you don't have one.

Comment: I agree with this.  Moreover, if you haven't racked your cider at least once, the tap can have lots of sediment stuck in it.  The tap is very useful when used in a bottling bucket, but after fermentation I prefer to use a siphon...

Comment: One more thing I like to do, or use to before I began the never ending moving from place to place. I had a racking station, and I placed my tubs and carboys up on a shelf set slightly a kilter so most sediment would end up in one _corner_ of the bottom. This also allowed me to rack without disturbing sediment when lifting a carboy to racking height. It was already there.

Comment: Regarding sediment in the tap you can use a drinking glass to catch the first 1/4 to 1/2 cup of the cider.  This helps flush the sediment out of the tap before you bottle.